# What does it mean for a classic field to be defined in terms of stochastic parameters?

Tags: cosmology, terminology, definition, classical-field-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm writing a bachelor's thesis related to inflationary cosmology and I don't quite understand some things about a paper I've been reading called [Signals of a Quantum Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.09149). Specifically, the paper introduces a classical field as an integral over $a_{\textbf{k}}^\dagger$'s and $a_{\textbf{-k}}$'s (eq. 2.2). They call the $a_{\textbf{k}}^\dagger$ *stochastic parameters* and require only
$$
\langle a_{\textbf{k}}^\dagger a_{\textbf{k}'}\rangle=\langle a_{\textbf{k}'}a_{\textbf{k}}^\dagger\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\delta (\textbf k - \textbf k').
$$

I don't understand how to interpret these $a_{\textbf{k}}^\dagger$'s. I know some basically classical field theory, but the usage of 'stochastic parameters' is new to me. What kind of objects are they, or is there some introductory text I can read about it? I have a more mathematical background, so an explanation in terms of domains and codomains would also work.

Comment: That word "classical" can be misleading. To me it looks like they rather use it to distinguish uncertainty that comes from quantum phenomena vs. coming from classical probability/statistical physics. This paper is short but could be hard to understand without more background in Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory. Classical field theory is usually only an introductory chapter for the latter. It could be easier to start on Quantum mechanics and learn what distinguishes its complex probability amplitudes from "classical" probabilities.